# Is there any function in jquery to replace whole html code with the new one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We use `document.write()` in javascript to write anything in the HTML document. Can this be done with the help of Jquery on click of a button in a new tab?

```
var newHTML = "<html><head></head><body><div class='test-class'><p>this is a test div for the next page print with external appended jquery script.</p><h1>this is heading for extra content in page</h1></div></body></html>";
$(document.body).append(newHTML);
```

This is not working. I want that, on click of a button newHTML's content open in new tab

Comment: You should avoid document.write. It has some uses, but most of the time it is the wrong tool for the job. It is sort of like opening a window with a hammer. It works, but there is a better way to open a window.

Comment: What functionality are you looking from document.write that you cannot get from jQuery append?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has many functions for manipulating the DOM, but none equivalent to `document.write`.

There's no reason for it to have anything like that. It doesn't interact with element selection (jQuery's core feature) or benefit from any kind of simplification.

Remember that jQuery is just a set of JavaScript functions written by other people. Loading jQuery doesn't prevent you from using `document.write`.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add content to your page using jQuery using several methods. Here are a few that may help you:

```
$( "body" ).append( "your content" );
```

```
$( "div" ).html( "<span class='blue'>your content</span>" );
```

Comment: That won't work. The question specified "in a new tab" - which is a different document.

Comment: @Quentin The question actually says "on click of a button *in a new tab*" so I think this is a more sensible answer because `document.write() == "ewww"`

Comment: This won't help as it won't insert the content in a new tab. This is only useful for inserting content on the same page or tab.